# How to change ceiling light on a flush flat light fixture

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, light

My ceiling light fixture looks like this. I can't seem to be able to remove it no matter which way I try. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Typically you pull straight down on the outside frame. Does it move at all? Is it covered in a layer of paint sealing it to the ceiling?

Comment: It was the layer of paint that prevented it from moving. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab the edges carefully and pull down. Should slide down on metal spring catches on two sides. Once down about an inch, you'll see them. Sqeeze together, like tongs, and pull down and out of the slot in the recessed frame. Some have coil springs but if it's difficult to pull down, it's probably the sqeeze style.